# bind event to anchor tags with div loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working with jQuery 1.7.2.

I have create a custom plug-in that loads a modal - i.e., a div with content. (`$modal`)

When the div is shown to the user, I would like to bind a function to all anchor tags in the div that has the class `Close` assigned to it.

**I have something like this:**

```
  $(".Close", $modal).die().on("click", hitMe());
```

The problem I am having is that every time the div loads, the `hitMe()` function is always firing. I only want this to fire when the user clicks an anchor in the div with class Close.

Any idea where I am going wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling hitMe inside the .on function.
What you need to do is pass the function as an argument

```
$(".Close", $modal).die().on("click", hitMe);
```

Comment: Cant believe that was it, so obvious! Thanks for pointing it out.